# Sort the file in unix using first six characters of a line

Tags: sorting, unix

I want to sort the file using first six characters of a line.
It should ignore the default sort order after the sixth character.
I have tried using the below command, but the system takes the default sort order after the sixth character.

```
sort -k 1,6 filename.txt
```

Input File : "filename.txt"

```
09289720150531N201505220820D20150514
09289720150531N201505220820A20150516
08806020150531N201505290810D20150526
08806020150531N201505290810A20150528
```

Output should be:

```
08806020150531N201505290810D20150526
08806020150531N201505290810A20150528
09289720150531N201505220820D20150514
09289720150531N201505220820A20150516
```

But my command output is:

```
08806020150531N201505290810A20150528
08806020150531N201505290810D20150526
09289720150531N201505220820A20150516
09289720150531N201505220820D20150514
```

Answer (score 6):

The option as shown uses the *field* position.  If you change that to something like `-k1.1,1.6` it will use the *character* position in the first field.  This is an [extended POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) feature, likely to be provided on most platforms.

However, in your example there are only two distinct values in character positions 1-6: `088060` and `092897`.  The standard sort command does not have a feature for *ignoring* columns, but only for *using* columns.  While GNU sort provides an extension (`-s` for "disabling last-resort comparison"), Solaris sort does not have such an extension.  After the sort-keys have been taken into account, it sorts by the remainder of the lines.

There *is* some vague wording in its manual which hints that `-u` will do what you want:

> When there are multiple key fields, later keys  are compared only after all earlier keys compare equal. Except  when  the  `-u` option is specified, lines that otherwise compare equal are ordered as if  none  of the  options  `-d`,  `-f`,  `-i`, `-n` or `-k` were present (but with `-r` still in effect,  if it  was  specified) and with all bytes in the lines significant to the comparison.

However — revisiting this — the wording from this is misleading since `-u` is used to filter duplicates.

A comment suggests that `-k1.1,1.6` could be shortened to `-k1.6`, and testing with Solaris 10 confirmed that would work.  That is with `/usr/bin/sort`, of course.  On my copy of Solaris 10, there is an additional copy of sort, in `/opt/sfw/bin/sort`:

```
$ /opt/sfw/bin/sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.97
```

and *that* program supports the `-s` option noted above.  With that option, the program produces the output which was requested.

Comment: I just tried this command, but it didn't work in Solaris environment.

Comment: sort -k1.1,1.6 samplee.txt

Comment: @srisriv `sort -k1.6 file` should be enough.